# Using angular.js $resource with express framework

Tags: node.js, express, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and node.js/express framework. I am working on a small application which uses angular and express frameworks. I have express app running with couple of end points. One for POST action and one for GET action. I am using node-mysql module to store and fetch from mysql database.

This application is running on my laptop.

### **angular.js client:**

#### controller

```
function ItemController($scope, storageService) {
   $scope.savedItems = storageService.savedItems();
   alert($scope.savedItems);
}
```

#### service

```
myApp.service('storageService', function($resource) {

    var Item = $resource('http://localhost\\:3000/item/:id',
      {
         id:'@id',
      },

      {
         query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
      }
    );

    this.savedItems = function() {
      Item.query(function(data){
      //alert(data);
          return data;
       });
    }
```

### Express server with mysql database:

```
...
app.get('/item', item.list);
...

items.js
---------
exports.list = function(req, res) {

   var sql = 'select * from item';

   connect: function() {
      var mysql = require('mysql');
      var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'admin',
        database : 'test'
      });
      return connection;
   },

   query: function(sql) {
      var connection = this.connect();
      return connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
         if (err) throw err;
         return results;
      });
   },
   res.send(results);
};
```

When I send static array of items (json) from server, $scope.savedItems() is getting populated.

but when I access items in database, even though server is returning items, $scope.savedItems in client is empty. Using $http directly did not help either.

I read async nature of $resource and $http from angular.js documentation and I am still missing something or doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the async nature of angular $resource.

```
$scope.savedItems = storageService.savedItems();
```

Returns immediately an empty array, which is populated after the data returns. Your `alert($scope.savedItems);` will therefore show only an empty array. If you look at your `$scope.savedItems` a little bit later you would see that it has been populated. If you would like to use the data just after it has been returned you can use a callback:

```
$scope.savedItems = storageService.savedItems(function(result) {alert(result); });
```

Comment: Thanks Aleksander. I am not  seeing the callback getting the value (and binding with scope) when view renders. I am seeing empty view rendered all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a quick note. You could also watch the savedItems.

```
function ItemController($scope, storageService) {
   $scope.savedItems = storageService.savedItems();
   $scope.$watch(function() {
      return $scope.savedItems;
   }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (typeof newValue !== 'undefined') {
         // Do something cool
      }
   },
   true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Flek. I tried using watch and not getting the values populated. When UI renders, there were no values to bind to.  Not sure how to control the timing of rendering and binding the values.

Comment: This answer has  couple issues.  As written, `storageService.savedItems()` doesn't return anything since it relies a callback to actually retrieve the data (as caught by Aleksander Blomskøld below).  2nd, you probably want `$watchCollection` and not `$watch`.

Comment: @KevinStone $watchCollection is not available in the stable release of AngularJS as far as I know (1.0.8 by this time) and apart from that you can do everything with $watch. Please be so kind and explain why you think it's superior and the problem with $watch.

Comment: `$watch` only compares objects by identity, so [1] != [1] even though they have the same members in the list.  You *can* pass a third parameter (after the getter and the callback) to `true` and `$watch` compares by object equality instead.  See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Comment: @KevinStone I do know that but still $watchCollection is not available in the stable release so telling people $watch is an issue is problematic in my mind. Apart from that why don't you just edit my answer if things have been changing since I posted it instead of a simple down vote...

Answer (score 0):

i suspect, node is not returning mysql results. The fact that it works for static files and not for mysql rules out issues with angular. Can you add firebug logs for the http call or chrome developer logs. This can shed more light on the matter